# Filtering a python list with some urls, based particular parameters

Tags: python, list, url, filter

For example, we have the following list of URLs:

```
all_links = ['afisha.ru/movie/y2010-2019/vybor-afishi/', 
'afisha.ru/movie/257915/', 
'afisha.ru/movie/257574/', 
'afisha.ru/movie/258600/', 
'afisha.ru/movie/257467/', 
'afisha.ru/movie/246562/', 
'afisha.ru/movie/changed_world/']
```

and there some links which I should remove ('afisha.ru/movie/y2010-2019/vybor-afishi/', 'afisha.ru/movie/changed_world/').

I would like to filter my list such that it should return only URLs which has some numbers after 'movie'.
Output should be:

```
all_links = ['afisha.ru/movie/257915/', 
'afisha.ru/movie/257574/', 
'afisha.ru/movie/258600/', 
'afisha.ru/movie/257467/', 
'afisha.ru/movie/246562/']
```

Please could you advise me, is there some way without using regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work (i consider all numbers have 6 digits, you can adjust it to check for fewer digits if needed):

```
result=[i for i in all_links if i[i.index('movie/')+6:i.index('movie/')+12].isdigit()]

print(result)

['afisha.ru/movie/257915/', 'afisha.ru/movie/257574/', 'afisha.ru/movie/258600/', 'afisha.ru/movie/257467/', 'afisha.ru/movie/246562/']
```